# How to rewrite this double sum in more elegant manner?

Tags: summation, transformation

I want to rewrite the following double sum as a sum of two terms (eq 3)but I am struggling with the limits in (3).

\begin{align}
y(n,m) &= \sum_{i=0}^{N}\sum_{j=0}^{M}h(i,j)x(n-i,m-j) \tag{1}\\
&= h(0,0)x(n,m) + \sum_{j=1}^{M}h(0,j)x(n,m-j) + \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=0}^{M}h(i,j)x(n-i,m-j) \tag{2}\\
&= h(0,0)x(n,m) + \color{red}{\sum_{i=?}^{N}\sum_{j=?}^{M}h(i,j)x(n-i,m-j)} \tag{3}
\end{align}

can someone please suggest a more elegant way of writing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=0}^{N}\sum_{j=\max(1-i, 0)}^{M}h(i,j)x(n-i,m-j)$$

When $i=0, \max(1-i,0)=1$

When $i>0, \max(1-i,0)=0$